# Is Mica non-conductive?

Tags: semiconductors, electricity, insulation, conductors, insulator

Are mica flakes like ones found in makeup and body lotions completely non conductive and should I be worried if it gets inside the components of my computer? Or should I be more concerned about regular household dust since it can carry static electricity?

Comment: ANY dielectric, including mica, can "carry" static electricity.

Answer (score 3):

> completely non conductive

no such thing exists, only "only conductive by a degree negligible to my problem".

But yes, Mica has an extremely low conductance. We technically call it an *isolator*, and Mica plates are commonly used as thermally-conducting, electrically-isolating spacers.

Of course, that quality doesn't apply to the rest of the components in makeups and body lotions, so if you got body lotion in your PC, clean it and hope for the best.

> Or should I be more concerned about regular household dust since it can carry static electricity?

Any body can "carry" static electricity. That's actually called a charge. So, there's nothing special about dust here.

You'll also notice that w.r.t. to most properties the main difference between makeup powder and dust is whether you'd put it on your face.

Comment: No telling what they will put on their faces - a lot of make-up is made from used cooking oil... Do you want to kiss last week’s fish ‘n chips??

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know OP nearly well enough to be willing to answer that.

Comment: (@SolarMike also, technically most surfaces you'd kiss on a human consist of significant amounts of dead cell material. Not quite sure whether cooking oil is so much worse.)

Comment: Well, I will swallow a spoonful of cooking oil fresh from the container, but old used - no chance...

Comment: @SolarMike what do you think your fries are saturated with? :P let's not talk about food, I haven't had breakfast.

Comment: Then I wish you Bon Appetit ! whether it's just coffee or more substantial...

Comment: @SolarMike You guys are taking all of the romance out of EE.SE!

Comment: Anyway, getting back to the topic at hand, "silvered mica" capacitors were at one time the most stable, low-leakage type you could get.

Comment: I would add that mica is commonly an _insulator_ which I suppose may be synonymous with _isolator_ but it could also be a regional language difference.